# Multiple jQuery modal overlays with unique id's

Tags: jquery, simplemodal, multiple-instances

I'm a bit stuck on this - I am using a Wordpress shortcode with a modal overlay plugin to insert multiple overlays into the content editor. However, I'm trying not to repeat my jQuery code multiple times for each ID.

As you can see in the shortcode I can set the ID of the overlay in Wordpress's editor like so:

**Shortcode**

```
[osu_overlay linktext="Text for link" oid="1"] ... content for overlay ... [/osu_overlay]
```

This creates the following HTML markup:

**HTML**

```
<a id="overlaylink-1" class="overlaybox" rel="overlaybox-1" href="javascript:void(0);">Text for link</a>
<div id="overlaybox-1" class="overlaybox" style="display:none;"> ... content for overlay ...</div>
```

This is the jQuery I don't want to have to repeat for each ID i.e. for overlaylink-1, overlaylink-2 etc.

**jQuery**

```
// Check if .overlaylink exists first
if($("#overlaylink-1").length == 0) {
    // #overlay-link-1 doesn't exist
} else {
    // Start overlay
    $('#overlaylink-1').click(function(){
        function dialogFadeIn() {
            dialogFadeIn.data.fadeIn('slow');
        }
        $("#overlaybox-1").modal({
            persist: true,
            onOpen: function(dialog) {
                dialog.overlay.fadeIn('medium', function () {
                    dialog.data.hide();
                    dialog.container.show()
                    dialog.data.fadeIn('medium');
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Is there a way of writing the jQuery code above so that it accounts for all IDs i.e. 'overlaylink-x' and overlaybox-x' where x is any number?

Thanks for any help

Osu

-*****- **EDIT** -*****-

Here's the final jQuery code - I've updated the HTML and Shortcode as well to include rel="" which is needed for this jQuery plugin code to work. Thanks to @DingoEatingFuzz for this solution (below).

**New jQuery**

```
// Check if .overlaylink exists first
if($(".overlaylink").length == 0) {
    // nada bc doesn't exist
} else {

    // Get Box to overlay from link rel
    var link = $('overlay-link-1'),
        box = $('#' + link.attr('rel'));

    // Plugin for showing overlay
    (function($) {
        $.fn.osuModal = function(options) { 
            // $.fn is the jQuery plugin object
            // make sure to loop in case the selector specified returns more than one object
            // make sure to return to support function chaining
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.click(function() {
                    function dialogFadeIn() {
                        dialogFadeIn.data.fadeIn('slow');
                    }
                    $('#' + $this.attr('rel')).modal({
                        persist: true,
                        onOpen: function(dialog) {
                            dialog.overlay.fadeIn('medium', function() {
                                dialog.data.hide();
                                dialog.container.show();
                                dialog.data.fadeIn('medium');
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }); // End '$this.click(function()'
            }); // End 'return this.each(function()'
        }
    })(jQuery);

    // Run the plugin
    $('.overlaylink').osuModal();

}
```

**WP Shortcode PHP**

This is in case anyone wants to do the same in Wordpress (you place this in your functions.php file):

```
// Shortcode for overlays
function osu_overlay($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('linktext' => '#', 'oid' => '#'), $atts));
    return '<a class="overlaylink" id="overlaylink-' . $oid . '" rel="overlaybox-' . $oid . '" href="javascript:void(0);">' . $linktext . '</a><div class="overlaybox" id="overlaybox-' . $oid . '" style="display:none;">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('osu_overlay', 'osu_overlay');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are ways to do what you are asking, I think you are creating a problem for yourself that can be avoided with different markup.

I would reference the `div` in the `a` tag like this:

`<a href='#' id='overlay-link-1' rel='overlaybox-1'>Text For Link</a>`

This way, the selector for the box can be derived from the link.

```
var link = $('overlay-link-1'),
    box = $('#' + link.attr('rel'))
;
```

Now `id` of the `div` and the `id` and `rel` of the anchor tag aren't important, as long as they match. The last step is to abstract the modal feature into a plugin for a simple interface.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.osuModal = function(options) { // $.fn is the jQuery plugin object
        // make sure to loop in case the selector specified returns more than one object
        // make sure to return to support function chaining
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.click(function() {
                function dialogFadeIn() {
                    dialogFadeIn.data.fadeIn('slow');
                }
                $('#' + $this.attr('rel')).modal({
                    persist: true,
                    onOpen: function(dialog) {
                        dialog.overlay.fadeIn('medium', function() {
                            dialog.data.hide();
                            dialog.container.show();
                            dialog.data.fadeIn('medium');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
})(jQuery);
```

Lastly, call the modals however you feel like.

```
$('.generic-class-for-all-modals').osuModal();
$('#specific-modal').osuModal();
$('#generated-modal-1').osuModal();
$('#generated-modal-1 #generated-modal-2').osuModal();
```

Comment: Thanks loads for this. I had to change a couple of things in there (closing brackets etc), but this is perfect. I've updated the question to show the final jQuery code and the modification to the HTML / Shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

To find an element with an `id` that starts with a given string:

```
$('a[id^="overlaylink"]')
$('div[id^="overlaybox"]')
```

Note that I'm using the element-type to reduce the number of elements that jQuery, or the browser, needs to search through in order to find the relevant elements. This isn't necessary, but reduces the work-load a little.

Given that these functions necessarily return arrays of elements, you'll have to iterate through that array with `each()` and then use the index (`each(function(index){ /*...*/})`) to target the specific elements if the number itself is relevant (I'm assuming that `#overlaylink-1` should probably show/act-on `#overlaybox-1`).

References:

- [attribute-starts-with selector: `attribute^="value"`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: Thanks for this, I've had a go at trying this (apologies, my JS / jQuery skills are still fairly basic), but I can only get the first overlay to work. Bear in mind, I've added a class to my links now (updated the example above). Can you see how I can fix my code? http://pastie.org/3713597